# Store canvas coordinates to local storage using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, angular-local-storage

I want to store drawing canvas coordinates  to local storage using angular.js i got the coordinates but can"t able to push values to local storage.

getting values from this

```
draw(lastX, lastY, currentX, currentY);
```

and to store value to local storage

```
app.controller('app', function ($scope, $http, $localStorage) {
    // Set a default
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        "lines": [] 
    });

    $scope.cloneItem = function () {
        $scope.$storage.lines.push({
            "lastX":lastX ,
            "lastY": lastY,
            "currentX": currentX,
            "currentY": currentY
        });
    }
});
```

i can"t able to get the values  `lastX lastY currentX currentY`

[Plunker Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/8u21Zj5JwUrPX2NK3JZJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Plunker did not work for me, lastX variable is undefined when I click the button. But I copy pasted code and I put values manually and seem that it works, so I think the problem is that you should check if variable is defined before store them.

Also, you need init lines in localStorage before setting its default value, or will throw an error later trying to store in an undefined value.

http://embed.plnkr.co/kbrRd2fYlL3oW07iI8Hm/

Comment: I know how to store values to locally but my problem is I'm not getting the value.. This is not a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

setup you variables at scope

```
app.controller('app', function($scope, $http, $localStorage) {
  // Set a default
  $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
    "lines": []
  });

  $scope.cloneItem = function() {
    $scope.$storage.lines.push({
      "lastX": $scope.lastX,
      "lastY": $scope.lastY,
      "currentX": $scope.currentX,
      "currentY": $scope.currentY
    });
    alert('$scope.lastX11111 -' + $scope.lastX)

  }
});
```

to

```
app.directive("drawing", function() {

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');

      // variable that decides if something should be drawn on mousemove
      var drawing = false;

      element.bind('mousedown', function(event) {
        if (event.offsetX !== undefined) {
          scope.lastX = event.offsetX;
          scope.lastY = event.offsetY;
        } else {
          scope.lastX = event.layerX - event.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
          scope.lastY = event.layerY - event.currentTarget.offsetTop;
        }

        // begins new line
        ctx.beginPath();

        drawing = true;
      });

      element.bind('mousemove', function(event) {
        if (drawing) {
          // get current mouse position
          if (event.offsetX !== undefined) {
            scope.currentX = event.offsetX;
            scope.currentY = event.offsetY;
          } else {
            scope.currentX = event.layerX - event.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
            scope.currentY = event.layerY - event.currentTarget.offsetTop;
          }

          draw(scope.lastX, scope.lastY, scope.currentX, scope.currentY);
          // console.log(lastX, lastY, currentX, currentY);
          // set current coordinates to last one
          scope.lastX = scope.currentX;
          // console.log(lastX, lastY, currentX, currentY);
          scope.lastY = scope.currentY;
        }

      });

      element.bind('mouseup', function(event) {
        // stop drawing
        drawing = false;
      });

      // canvas reset
      function reset() {
        element[0].width = element[0].width;
      }

      function draw(lX, lY, cX, cY) {
        // line from
        ctx.moveTo(lX, lY);
        // to
        ctx.lineTo(cX, cY);
        // color
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#4bf";
        // draw it
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Qcqua0gjoAfya6xkQFiX?p=preview